# Postgresql - Map a Linux user to login

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I want to **map Linux's root user to Postgres** user, like if I enter psql in root user it should go the PostgreSQL cli without asking any authentication.

I tried to add an entry in pg_ident.conf and make the necessary changes in pg_hba.conf, but it didn't work.

```
psql: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
```

`Postgresql Version 9.6`

```
pg_ident.conf
# MAPNAME       SYSTEM-USERNAME PG-USERNAME
root                 root            postgres

pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE USER   ADDRESS         METHOD
local   all     all                     peer map=root 
host    all     all     127.0.0.1/32    ident map=root
```

Any suggestions to achieve this?

I need to map multiple Linux users. The above one is for who all are using root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, it comes to end.

The problem is I need to replace the below line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

with the following line:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer  map=root
```

That's it, no more changes.

Got this from:

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/1069138/is-pg-ident-conf-working)

Answer (score 1):

A couple notes on this

- this only works on "peer" connections - i.e., non-network connections over a unix socket.

  - Importantly, specifying `-h localhost` makes it a network connection.
- In my experience, you still have to use the client side `-U` argument to specify what user you want on your command line.

  - e.g. `psql -U postgres`

Answer (score 0):

You need to reload the configuration, with `pg_ctl reload` or `kill -HUP` to the postmaster process. *(You did not mention it in your question so I suppose you forgot about it.)*